# How to align a selectize control with a boostrap button next to it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js

I am using boostrap 2.3 and I try to horizontally align a selectize control with a bootstrap button next after it.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        b
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">...</a>
        <select class="selectized input-large">
            <option>...</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">...</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following [this issue](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/197), I've tried to change the style this way (inline and negative top margin):

```
.selectize-control { display: inline-block; margin-top: -60px; }
```

It is better (inline), but not perfectly aligned (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0my82e2f/)):

[image: Misaligned selectize control]

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle please.

Comment: try adding a vertical-align:middle

Comment: @Steevan yes sure https://jsfiddle.net/0my82e2f/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the selectize library and vertical alignment middle to  `.selectize-control`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contract').selectize();
});
```

```css
.selectize-control {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1">XXX</div>
    <div class="span1">XXX</div>
    <div class="span10">XXX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1">a</div>
    <div class="span1">b</div>
    <div class="span10"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">button 1</a>

      <select id="contract" class="selectized input-large">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
      </select>
      <button id="cmdContractCopy" class="btn btn-primary">button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1">YYY</div>
    <div class="span1">YYY</div>
    <div class="span10">YYY</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/css/selectize.bootstrap2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I think it makes more sense to add these styles to a div wrapped around the select so you don't have to apply to every selectize

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0my82e2f/2/)

```
    .left{
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
    }
```